# ReactJS registering inside my azure tenant

Tags: reactjs, azure, rest, authentication

I have a question, Is there a way to register my client side application(Reactjs hosted outside my Azure tenant) so that it can authenticate and access my Rest Api(hosted in Azure tenant app service protected by AAD).

Comment: Do you just want to know how to resister an Azure AD app to present your client side application? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis

Comment: Sorry I am new to this MSI stuff, can I register an app even its outside my tenant azure?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether we can register an app even its outside my tenant azure, the answer is **YES**.

That is how it works, saying that integrate AAD authorization into your application to access your API or Azure resources.

Here is [Quickstart: Configure a client application to access web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis) for your reference.